# Ngx-logger implementation in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am implementing ngx-logger in my angular application and I am following [this](https://medium.com/@ahmedhamedTN/enable-disable-angular-logging-based-on-production-environment-using-ngxlogger-dee531fb8374) link to implement it.

In this link full logger code is at component level.

Just want to know do I need to implement anything related to logging in my html pages or procedure given in above link is sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

Article does not cover Testing part.

In your `spec` files you need:

```
import { LoggerTestingModule } from 'ngx-logger/testing';
```

and add `LoggerTestingModule` to `TestBed` `imports`.

Comment: ngx-logger does not provide this export anymore.

Comment: Fixed comment. Import should be from `'ngx-logger/testing';`